# F# How to convert a list of tuples into a parrallel array

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I am new to the functional programming and F#

I'm trying to convert a list of tuples into parallel lists, for example

```
let results = [("foo",3);("bar", 4)};("bazz", 8)]
// do something to convert it
// output = ["foo";"bar";"bazz"], output2 = [3;4;8]
```

What I attempted to was this

```
let issue = []
let count = []

for tpl in results do
    fst tpl |> issue
    snd tpl |> count
```

But obviously this wont compile.

I am getting the list of tuples from the statement

```
let results = IssueData |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the first part: there is `List.unzip`:

```
> let results = [("foo",3);("bar", 4);("bazz", 8)];;

val results : (string * int) list = [("foo", 3); ("bar", 4); ("bazz", 8)]

> let (issue, count) = List.unzip results;;

val issue : string list = ["foo"; "bar"; "bazz"]
val count : int list = [3; 4; 8]
```

if I get you right this is all you want to know so you can write

```
let (issues, count)= IssueData |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList |> List.unzip
```

as well.

#### remark

- In case you are wondering - you still need the `Seq.toList` in F# 4 as there still is no `Seq.unzip` ;) (it's one of the few things that did not get normalized to all of List/Array/Seq)
- if you are new to FP/F# it is a nice exercise to reimplement `List.unzip` yourself (hint: as always there are the two cases: `[]` and `(a,b):rest`)